# Modeling a database for a heater domotic app

Tags: database-design, mysql

Imagine a domotic webapp, to command a heater.

You could setup N plans, for a plan I mean a similar table:

```
+----+---------+--------------------+
| id | name    | target_temperature |
+----+---------+--------------------+
| 1  | confort | 19                 |
+----+---------+--------------------+
| 2  | hot     | 22                 |
+----+---------+--------------------+
| 3  | night   | 17                 |
+----+---------+--------------------+


PSEUDOCODE
(if plan is confort && temperature<19 then heater on)
```

Imagine you would setup a similar scenario:

```
MONDAY:

from 00:00 to 07:00 >> plan is night
from 07:00 to 08:00 >> plan is hot
from 16:00 to 18:00 >> plan is hot
from 18:00 to 22:00 >> plan is confort
from 22:00 to 23:59 >> plan is night
```

[...]

```
SATURDAY:

from 00:00 to 23:59 >> plan is confort
```

Note that on monday from the 08:00 to the 18:00 there is no plan. Software will be setup OFF the heater.

How you would design the database of the days? A singular table with 7 colums (from Monday to Sunday) and every columns N rows? I don't like it, because saturday is totally different from monday.

A singular table with 24 (or 48) rows and 7 column? WHere the rows goes from 00:00 to 23:59

```
+-----+-------+-------+---------+-----+---------+-------+
| id  | hour  | M     | T       | […] | S       | S     |
+-----+-------+-------+---------+-----+---------+-------+
| 1   | 00:00 | night | hot     |     | night   | night |
+-----+-------+-------+---------+-----+---------+-------+
| 2   | 00:30 | night | night   |     | confort | null  |
+-----+-------+-------+---------+-----+---------+-------+
| 3   | 01:00 | night | night   |     | confort | null  |
+-----+-------+-------+---------+-----+---------+-------+
| 4   | 01:30 | hot   | confort |     | confort | null  |
+-----+-------+-------+---------+-----+---------+-------+
| 5   | 02:00 | hot   | hot     |     | confort | null  |
+-----+-------+-------+---------+-----+---------+-------+
| 6   | 02:30 | null  | null    |     | confort | hot   |
+-----+-------+-------+---------+-----+---------+-------+
| […] |       |       |         |     |         |       |
+-----+-------+-------+---------+-----+---------+-------+
| 50  | 23:30 | hot   | hot     |     | null    | null  |
+-----+-------+-------+---------+-----+---------+-------+
| 51  | 23:59 | night | night   |     | night   | null  |
+-----+-------+-------+---------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And where the NULL means "Hey! Put the heater OFF!" ...

So, query to get the CURRENT APPLICABLE PLAN could be a simple

```
SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE hour = 

(

SELECT MAX(hour) FROM TEST WHERE hour < CURTIME()

)
```

But in this case the difficult could be select the right day! How select only the "Monday" column?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem arises from the fact that your `TEST` table is not in NF1

A more normalized model will be something like this:

[image]

The table you name `TEST` I call `SCHEDULE_DETAIL`, data woul dbe like this:

[image]

The query would be like this:

```
select
    p.plan_id,
    p.name,
    p.temp
from
    schedule s join
    schedule_detail sd on (sd.sch_id=sd.sch_id) join
    plan p on (sd.plan_id=p.plan_id) join
    day_of_week d on (sd.dow_id=d.dow_id)
where
    s.sch_id=1 and --we are using schedule 1 this time of year
    d.dow_id=1 and --monday, we can substitute the literal with a
                       --function that returns day of week (0-6)
    curtime() >= sd.start_hour and curtime() <= sd.end_hour;
```

**NOTE:**

- Some restrictions cannot be modeled so you will have to write a sanity procedure to check that no two rows of `SCHEDULE_DETAIL` for the same `schedule_id` have time overlap. In your example the first two rows for monday have a time overlap (one ends at 07:00 and the next one begins at 07:00, I corrected the time overlap in the sample data I provide)
- A check constraint must be added so `start_hour < end_hour`
- You can have different schedules and switch them during the year as you wish.
- You can create a view from that query (minus the where conditions) so you query that view instead of making the joinds all the time.
- **When the query returns no rows, switch off the heater.**

Comment: I did not understand your SCHEDULE table. What's contain NAME column? Thank you very much ;)...

Comment: Ops. maybe schedule could be "from may to september leave the heater off totally" and "from Jan, 1st, to Jan 6th I'm on the snow, so start the heater at 12°C? To defrozen it?"

Comment: Just a human readable description for your schedule, like 'AUTUM' or 'NO-ONE-HOME'. So users can select one by a name from a GUI.

Comment: You coud improve the schedule table by adding start_date and end_date, although that I did not contenplate.

Comment: Genius answer. If you don't offend, I'll accept in some hour, just to see if someone has others ideas. But, your design is very well, IMHO ;)